# url rewriting in wordpress of wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

url rewriting in wordpress of wp-admin.wp-admin not login and url goes to home,
http://www.vivaindia.es/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vivaindia.es%2Fhome%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Answer (score 0):

You may have an issue with a wrong siteurl in the wp_options table in your database. You can look at the [Login Trouble](http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble#Check_Your_URL_Options) page in the WordPress codex for a possible solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set the wp_redirect( home_url() ); wordpress function to the function.php file in themes so that's why you redirect to the home page and please try to change in wp_option table the feild option name siteurl and home

Answer (score 0):

I think, its due to permission change from your hosting server, you can contact them to solve this issue